# Javascript: Get selected radio and paste it on a label tag with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

I have a gender selection radio:

```
<div class="label-inputs" name="userFieldDiv" id="genderUserFieldDiv">      
    <label class="required">Sexo</label>                
    <input type="radio" class="check" value="F" name="userDto.gender" id="userDto.gender0">
    <label for="userDto.gender0">Femenino</label>
    <input type="radio" class="check" checked="checked" value="M" name="userDto.gender" id="userDto.gender1">
    <label for="userDto.gender1">Masculino</label>
</div>
```

I'm trying to use a jQuery script to get the selected radio and paste it inside of a label.

```
$("#userDto\\.gender").change(function() { $("#genderLabel").html(this.value); });
```

The problem is that I'm using Spring, and when I use `formRadioButton`, it generates the `id: userDto.gender` but adds a `0` and `1` to the options. So I'm out of ideas about how to make the next HTML to get the value of the selected radio.

```
<div name="userLabelDiv" id="genderUserLabelDiv">
    <label class="required">Sexo</label> 
    <label id="genderLabel">Masculino</label> 
</div>
```

Could someone guide me through the problem? I can't find where is my error in the JS code. Thank you

Comment: I could get the value reading inputs with the same attr name but I dont have idea how to do it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ids must be unique so what Spring is doing is just fine.  Just use the name attribute for the selector instead of the id.

```
$('input[name="userDto\\.gender"]').change( ... )
```